# Umbraco: creating user control

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I'm new to Umbraco. Currently is using v7.1.4.
I know that MVC partial views can be created under Settings > Partial Views.
If I have switch the rendering engine from MVC to webforms, where should I create .Net user control?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to CMayers answer, i generally prefer to create a separate project called usercontrols (just for the sake of knowing what it is) and then using xcopy in the build event copy the dll to the bin folder of the umbraco installation. Likewise the ascx pages are copied into the UserControls folder of the umbraco installation.

Then from the umbraco backend in the developer section, you can create the macro and associate the relevant ascx page to it.

Answer (score 0):

All your .NET Usercontrols should be created in the 'UserControls' folder that comes with the default Umbraco installation.

If you don't copy them to here, then you wont be able to access your user controls from the Macro section of the CMS "Choose a file to render".